# Select multiple html elements by clicking on one element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two images on my html page and I have one button named MOVE to move them left separately. To move them I have a Jquery function with selected class. 
I have two input fields each of them belongs to the particular image. My button has a click counter function so I need to get a count by clicking on the same button to both images separately into those two input fields.

I think when I select image 1, It's also should be selected input 1, and then the counter will count image 1's counts of moves and when I select image 2, It's also should be selected input 2, and then the counter will count image 2's counts of moves.

I don't know how to select multiple elements by clicking on one element. please help

My Jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".plan1").click(function() {                              //medium move
    // unselect others
    $(".plan1").removeClass("selected");
    // reselect this one
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});

$("#b1").click(function() {
    // animate selected
    $(".plan1.selected").animate({left:'+=20px'});
    $('#f1.selected').val(function(i, val) { return +val+1 });
});
});
```

HTML

```
<img src="imagesource" class="plan1" />
<img src="imagesource" class="plan1" />

<input type="text" id="f1" />
<input type="text" id="f2" />

<button id="b1">MOVE</button>
```

Comment: Hi...this would be a good time to read [mcve]. We all think in terms of code here and you need to show us that code. Basic html structure and click handlers you are currently using

Comment: (1) You only have one button? How does the button know which image you want to move? (2) Where do you store the counter? (3) What do you store in each input field?

Comment: when I click on the image, Jquery "this" method will know this image I want to move. I need to store the counter in each input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you started.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/16p9L2tf/)</kbd>

```js
$('#f1, #f2').val('0');

$(".plan1").click(function() {
 $(".plan1").removeClass("selected");
 $(this).addClass("selected");
});

$("#b1").click(function() {
    if ( $(".plan1.selected").length == 0 ) {
      alert("Pick a pic");
      return false;
    }
 var inpID = $(".plan1.selected").attr('id').slice(-1);
 var cnt = $('#f'+inpID).val();
 cnt++;
 $('#f'+inpID).val(cnt);

 $(".plan1.selected, #f"+inpID).animate({'left' : '+=50px' });
    $(".plan1.selected").removeClass("selected");
});
```

```css
* {position:relative;} /*  Critical! Allows elements to move  */
img, input{display:block;max-width:80px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="pic1" src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80" class="plan1" />
<img id="pic2" src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/animals" class="plan1" />

<input type="text" id="f1" />
<input type="text" id="f2" />

<button id="b1">MOVE</button>
```

---

Notes:

(1) In CSS, you must first make the elements `position:relative` because the default (`position:static`) cannot be styled with `left` or `right`

(2) In CSS, also must make the inline elements `img` and `input` into block elements, because inline elements cannot be animated left/right